# Removing brackets from MySQL query in Python with Flask

Tags: python, html, mysql, flask

I need to fill my drop-down menu with some information that I have in my Database. Everything is working well, except the query result format.

This is the code in my python file:

```
    results = None
    with db:
        cur = db.cursor()
        sql = "SELECT banco FROM bancos"
        try:
            cur.execute(sql)
            results = cur.fetchall()
            return render_template("cadastro.html", results=results)
```

This is my HTML:

```
        <select name="teste">
        {% for r in results %}
            <option name="{{ r }}">{{ r }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
        </select>
```

It's is filling my drop-down menu with all information that i Want but in this format:

('Banco do ABC Brasil S.A.',)

I dont want the brackets, comma, etc. I just want the result!

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You are printing out the entire row, which in this case only contains one field, `banco`. To print just a specific field, you need to use that field in your template.

Try

```
    <select name="teste">
    {% for r in results %}
        <option name="{{ r[0] }}">{{ r[0] }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
```

You may also be able to use `r['banco']` or `r.banco` depending on your database driver.

Comment: Tried this...returns nothing in the option field.

Comment: `r` should be a tuple. `r[0]` is the first element in the tuple.

Comment: Yes! I can't understand why it's returning nothing. Tried to use:
`return render_template("cadastro.html", results=results[0])` and It worked well returning the first record of the query formatted.

well, i'll keep trying...thanks!